# Create date sequence by factor level

Tags: r, date

I have a list of 100 observation units and a sequence of dates:

```
unit <- c(1:100)
date <- seq.Date(as.Date("2012-01-01"),as.Date("2012-12-01"), by = "month")
```

I want to create a new dataframe with each observational unit having a time unit. For example:

```
Unit     Date
 1    "2012-01-01"
 1    "2012-02-01"
 1    "2012-03-01"
 1    "2012-04-01"
 ................
 100   "2012-01-01"
 100   "2012-02-01"
 100   "2012-03-01"
 100   "2012-04-01"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
expand.grid(unit = unit, date = date)
```

If this is what you have in mind.

You can optionally order by unit as follows:

```
df <- expand.grid(unit = unit, date = date)
df <- df[order(df$unit), ]
```

Comment: A simple answer. Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not as concise as expand.grid, but more explicitly, you could do:

```
examp <- data.frame(Unit = rep(unit, each = length(date)), 
                    Date = rep(date, times = length(unit)))
```